# Class method to return inherited class

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

I need to create various custom fits with custom measures on different sets of data. I'm trying to create a class which holds the basic information required to call fits and forecasts, and I would like those fits and forecasts to also be objects which contains methods and attributes.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from dateutil import relativedelta


def ex(x, a, b):
    """Exponential function"""
    return a * b**x

def p2y(idx):
    """Evaluate number of periods to a year"""
    return int(12/(relativedelta.relativedelta(idx[-1],idx[-2]).months))

class fitter:
    """Hold fit parameters"""
    def __init__(self, use_y, kind, true_y=None):
        self.use_y = use_y
        if true_y==None:
            self.true_y=use_y
        else:
            self.true_y = true_y
        self.kind = kind
        self.p = p2y(use_y.sort_index().index)

    def fit(lookback):
        return fitter_fit(lookback)

class fitter_fit(fitter):
    """Perform fit over lookback number of years"""
    def __init__(self,lookback):
        super().__init__()
        n=int(lookback*self.p)
        x=np.linspace(1,n,n)
        dates=self.use_y.index[-n:]
        y=self.use_y.values[-n:]
        if self.kind=='exp':
            self.popt, self.pcov = curve_fit(ex, x, y)


qtrly=pd.DataFrame(
    index=[dt.datetime(2020,1,1),dt.datetime(2020,4,1),dt.datetime(2020,7,1),dt.datetime(2020,10,1)],
    data={'fre':[0.55,0.6,0.62,0.7]})
f=fitter(qtrly.fre,'exp')
f.fit(3)
```

I want to be able to create the `fitter` object to hold useful inputs, with a `fit` method which I can call for different years. The `fit` method should create a new object which contains all of the original attributes such as `true_y`, and also the new attributes such  as `popt` and `pcov`. I intend to add methods to the 'fit' class which will require these attributes.

UPDATE: Complete error message produced by the code above:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8660\3244407924.py in <module>
     42     data={'fre':[0.55,0.6,0.62,0.7]})
     43 f=fitter(qtrly.fre,'exp')
---> 44 f.fit(3)

TypeError: fit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

UPDATE: Thanks for the tips, the missing self parameter was an issue. I've been able to create the results I'm looking for by changing the class definitions to those below, though having one class object read out all of its attributes into the other, and then having the other object assign them all to itself seems clunky. Is there no way for the fitter_fit object to clone the assigned attributes of the fitter object?

```
class fitter:
    """Creates fit parameters over a lookback number of years"""
    def __init__(self, use_y, kind, true_y=None):
        self.use_y = use_y
        if true_y==None:
            self.true_y=use_y
        else:
            self.true_y = true_y
        self.kind = kind
        self.p = p2y(use_y.sort_index().index)
        
    def fit(self,lookback):
        return fitter_fit(self.use_y,self.kind,self.true_y,self.p,lookback)
                     
class fitter_fit:
    """Perform fit over lookback number of years"""
    def __init__(self,use_y,kind,true_y,p,lookback):
        self.lookback = lookback
        self.use_y = use_y
        self.kind = kind
        self.true_y = true_y,
        self.p = p
        n=int(lookback*self.p)
        x=np.linspace(1,n,n)
        dates=self.use_y.index[-n:]
        y=self.use_y.values[-n:]
        if self.kind=='exp':
            self.popt, self.pcov = curve_fit(ex, x, y)
```

Comment: Please post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Comment: `fitter.__init__` has two required arguments, `use_y` and `kind`. You aren't providing either of them when `fiter_fit.__init__` calls `super().__init__()`.

Comment: @chepner: My goal is for fitter_fit to pull the use_y and kind attributes off of the fitter object. In the code above, f already has those two attributes. When I call f.fit(3), I would like it to pull use_y and kind from itself.

Comment: You are currently creating a *new* instance of `fitter_fit` with no reference to the existing object that invokes the `fit` method. `fit` is also lacking the `self` parameter required of an instance method  (or rather, it's just called `lookback` instead of `self`)

Comment: Having a method specifically to generate an instance of a *subclass* is a bit odd. It would make more sense for `fitter_fit` to have a class method that takes an instance of `fit` as an argument. (Parent classes shouldn't need to know any details about subclasses; child classes almost by definition need to know the interfaces of their parents.)